# complex problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this problem in my homework and I need some help with how to approach the problem.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on the region $G$, $\gamma$ is a closed, smooth, G-contractable curve, and $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \gamma$. Prove that $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$ inside $ \gamma$.

I was thinking that Since $\gamma$ is a closed, smooth, G-contractable curve, we have $\int_\gamma f=\int_\gamma g=0$. We also know that for any closed, smooth, G-contractable curve $\sigma$ lying within $\gamma$, $\sigma\sim_G\gamma$. Therefore, 
$$\int_\gamma f=\int_\sigma f$$
$$\int_\gamma g=\int_\sigma g$$
and thus:
$$\int_\sigma f=\int_\sigma g=0$$

But I wasn't sure how to use "$f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \gamma$", or how to prove $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \sigma$.

Please help me... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: oh that's right! thank you!!!

Comment: I was just wondering if I forgot to consider something in this following proof as it seems really straight forward.. Let $w\in G$ be any point inside $\gamma$. From Cauchy's Integral Formula we have 
$$f(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-w}dz$$
$$g(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{g(z)}{z-w}dz$$
Since $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in \gamma$, $f(w)=g(w)$ for any $w$. That is, $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z$ inside $ \gamma$. thank you again...

Comment: @user30398 Nope, that's about it :) I mean, you need to mention that everything's valid because you're working on a curve homologous to zero, but otherwise, it's a-ok! PS, if you are satisfied with my answer you can click the little "check mark" which accepts the answer.